# Solution parabollic PDE system

Tags: functional-analysis, systems-of-equations, boundary-value-problem, parabolic-pde, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega := [0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$ be a domain and $u, w \in C^\infty (\Omega)$. Consider the system

\begin{align} 
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} &= D_u \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x ^2} - \lambda u + \beta w \\ 
 \frac{\partial w}{\partial t} &= D_w \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x ^2} + \alpha u - v \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} - \beta w. 
\end{align}

with $D_u, D_w, \lambda, \beta, \alpha, v \in \mathbb{R}$ constants and conditions

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty} u (x,t) &= 0, \qquad \lim_{x\to \infty} w (x,t) = 0 \\
u(0, t) &= f_u(t), \ \ \ w(0, t) = g_w(t) \\
u(x, 0) &= 0, \qquad w(x, 0) = 0
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^\infty u (x,t) + w (x,t) dx &= 1
\end{align}

**What I have done so far**

I have numerically solved the problem using the method of lines and found the steady states analytically solving. The solution seems to be a negative exponential.

Now **I want to find an explicit solution**. I tried to solve the first equation for $w$ and then replace it on the second. But the substitution yields a $4^{th}$ order PDE that I do not know how to solve.

Does anyone know how to find the explicit solution for this system of PDE?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think a Laplace transform in space might help. By the way, this problem seems reminiscent of a solution given by (if I remember correctly, though I'm probably wrong) Kolmogorov or Kirchoff, where you solve the heat equation with zero initial condition which has nonzero solution over the entire domain except at $\infty$. I believe the solution is something like a [flat function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function), which would seem to match your negative exponential solution (though I could be entirely wrong about all this).

Comment: @mattos Looking at the results for the numerical solution, it does not seem to be the case for a flat function. However, by "Laplace transform" do you mean a double Laplace transform? for $x$ and then for $t$?